# Изменение фонового изображения элемента (блока) с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток, дорогие программисты. Столкнулся с достаточно странной проблемой. Я пытаюсь средствами `jQuery` изменить фоновую картинку самого обычного `div`-a, у которого по умолчанию `background`'a нету. Но, почему-то, ничего не выходит. Я использовал `.css`(`'background-image', 'url()'`). Поиски в интернете дали достаточно много результатов, но почему-то у меня не заработал ни один. Использую новейший `jQuery 2.0`, но не думаю, что проблема в нем. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать. Особенно прошу, проверьте, прежде чем отправлять. Потому что вариантов я перепробовал не меньше десятка, заходя даже в обычный `JavaScript`. Но ничего рабочего так и не нашел. При этом задание фонового изображения в самом блоке работает. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- http://jsfiddle.net/SKuUh/
- [Switching a DIV background image with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-a-div-background-image-with-jquery)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, как всегда забыл кавычки. Проблема решена